# Unable to find ip of pi 3 for first time headless setup?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi3

Unable to find ip of pi 3 for first time headless setup ?
I have created ssh file and wpa_supplicant.conf on boot  partition
OS on pi : strech
my machine running on windows 10
I didnt find ip of pi3 on my routers client list also

Comment: I highly recommend something like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) so that you can connect to the Pi's serial console.  This works even if the network isn't configured properly. That makes it much easier to diagnose things.

Comment: You may want to move this question over to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.